# Determine translated type for generics at runtime

Tags: java, generics, runtime

My question is exactly similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326285/deciding-on-type-in-the-runtime-and-applying-it-in-generic-type-how-can-i-do-t). Just that, I want to do it in Java.

Suppose, I want to crate a list as:

```
List<a_type> myList = new ArrayList<a_type>();
```

The problem is that what `a_type` would be, is decided on the base of a condition. The two possible types are totally unrelated, having no superclass but Object in common. My problem will be solved if I can store the Type in a variable `requiredType` and use it as `List<requiredType>`. I am not sure if I'm just being greedy or foolish or ignorant in wanting this, but that's the situation.

Although not important, but the scenario that explains why I need it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544309/parent-child-model-for-dto).

---

PS: Please do not mention type-erasure. Kindly consider the situation as it is. I could have very well myself mentioned it in the question. If you think there are design issues, kindly read the situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544309/parent-child-model-for-dto) and suggest alternatives.

Comment: this isn't possible in Java, and I would go so far as to say your design is flawed if it requires this ...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Please suggest if you have a better option. "Your design is flawed" seems to be a favorite for this type of questions found anywhere on the internet :) Interesting part is, this is a situation, need to think of a solution.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible in Java, because of the type-erasure and due to the fact that generics is only limited to compiletime.

e.g.

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

During compiletime, when the the type-erasing is done becomes

```
List integers = new ArrayList();
```

The generics is only a way to tell the compiler, that the list should only deal with objects of type `Integer`, and let's it point it out if you have somewhere tried to add something other than `Integer` for type safety.

Answer (score 2):

The only effective (if “risky”) way I could see to do so, would be something akin to:

```
     List<?> myList = new ArrayList<?> ();

     /* … */

     final Object o = myList.get (0);

     if (o instanceof OneType) {
           OneType o1 = (OneType)o;
           /* … */
     } else if (o instanceof OtherType) {
           OtherType o2 = (OtherType)o;
           /* … */
     } else {
           throw new RuntimeException ("unexpected type found in list…");
     }
```

You will probably want to litter that code with @SuppressWarnings

Possibly a better(?) idea would be to implement at least a “marker interface” (without perhaps any methods) in both types, and use that as the commonality.

```
     public interface CanBeAddedToDualTypedList { };
     public class OneType implements CanBeAddedToDualTypeList { … };
     public class OtherType implements CanBeAddedToDualTypeList { … };


     List<CanBeAddedToDualTypedList> myList = 
                     new ArrayList<CanBeAddedToDualTypedList> ()
```

**Edit** I also put an answer on your related question, showing a concrete example of using a common interface for that specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Java generic are not available at runtime so not possible with java

Search for "Type Erasure" on google and you will understand it better.

Comment: Yeah, know about that. That's why I thought I might be a bit greedy here. But all I wanted to do was to initialize my generic list in a safe way. :(

Comment: unfortunately there is no way for that :(

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `a_type.class` object while that wont help you with generics, it can be used to add additional runtime type checks `class.cast(...)`.

Generics do not support runtime typing, the generic type itself does not exist at runtime. C# has a runtime class for each Generic type `List<String>` is different from `List<int>`. In java this is not the case both `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` degrade to `List` at runtime.

AFAIK (never tried it) extending a Generic class stores the type somewhere accessible to reflection `class StringList extends List<String>{}`, the StringList remembers the Generic type used to extend List.